# CSS <hr> width transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm attempting to create transitions on the social media links on https://ollynural.github.io/ but i'm having trouble making it work as expected.

When hovering on each icon, my aim is for the hr bar to smoothly transition both left and right sides to the correct point whilst making it smaller. At the moment it moves the beginning of the bar to the set point of the smaller part and then reduces it smoothly. I'm not really sure how to approach this, i'm mainly experimenting with css and transitions now.

I've made a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v8sbb5zL/) as best I can.

```css
.social-links {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
hr {
  width: 90%;
  border-top: 2px solid #8c8b8b;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .social-links {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
.social-links span {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .social-links span {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
.fa-github:hover {
  color: #64a4df;
}
.github-link:hover ~ .social-line {
  width: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 9%;
}
.fa-linkedin-square:hover {
  color: #64a4df;
}
.linkedin-link:hover ~ .social-line {
  width: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 34%;
}
.fa-twitter-square:hover {
  color: #64a4df;
}
.twitter-link:hover ~ .social-line {
  width: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 59%;
}
.fa-facebook-square:hover {
  color: #64a4df;
}
.facebook-link:hover ~ .social-line {
  width: 7.5%;
  margin-left: 84%;
}
.social-link {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-bar">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="social-links">

      <div class="col-xs-3 github-link social-link">
        <a href="https://github.com/OllyNural" target="github">
          <span class="fa fa-github"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 linkedin-link social-link">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/oliver-nural-43565497" target="linkedin">
          <span class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 twitter-link social-link">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/OliverNural" target="twitter">
          <span class="fa fa-twitter-square"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 facebook-link social-link">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Olly.Nural" target="facebook">
          <span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <hr class="social-line">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, Olly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing two properties here, `width` and `margin-left`.
Therefore, you need to set transition both for `width` (as you did) and for `margin-left`.
For it to work smoothly, you will need to set a numeric initial value for `margin-left'.
This worked for me:

```
hr {
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  border-top: 2px solid #8c8b8b;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, margin-left 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense, I will check tomorrow morning to see if it works for me, but hopefully this will be fine! Thank you

Comment: For others - Apparantly you cannot transition between margins if one is set to auto or unspecified. This answer worked between the links but only after i added a margin to the origin '.social-line' did it work perfectly! Thank you very much!